# C++, what is a good way to hash array data?

Tags: c++, hash, arrays, types

I have a curious problem and I am brainstorming possible solutions. The problem is such: I have a number of inputs (up to several thousand different ones), which basically differ in two-three arrays (arrays are a different size generaly, from size one up to couple thousand elements long).  the functions which process arrays take some time to initialize data, so i thought to cache function/functor together with data and store them in map.

now, how do i go about converting raw arrays into usable hashtable type?  i initially thought to read array into a string and use string as the key. is it good idea?  do you have better suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a need to look up specific keys?  I'm not sure what using a hash table is buying you here if you're just going to process one dataset after the next, which is what it sounds like.

Comment: @Joe yes, I do need to lookup keys. same data is processed using same function 10 or more times.

Comment: But how do you *know* which set you need to process again?  What I'm not understanding from your description is how do you know in your logic which dataset you need to retrieve again?

Comment: Which grows faster, the number of elements or the size of the keys? If you hash the entire key, then computing the hash of a key is O(key size), which may be significant. If you don't hash the entire key, then keys that differ only at the end will collide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are these arrays integer? If yes, just go with something like this

`hash = (hash + (324723947 + a[i])) ^93485734985;`

Similar thing would work fine for strings if you do it on all characters.
Finally, you may check out [extra libs here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/hash.html)

Comment: double precision, so technically they can be integers.

Comment: Then it would work perfectly. I would still hash them as integers.

Comment: this hash function, what is the collision rate? I am a bit worried about that

Comment: For float numbers it is going to be nearly perfectly random.
So collision rate would depend solely on your hash table size.